# How to Use Private key to encrypt a message and decrypt it using the same block's public key?

Tags: encryption, blockchain, solidity, digital-signature, private-key

I am building a DApp where I want to add a message to all the blocks that shows that the blocks are created by the same company i.e my website and no one can replicate that message. So, I think the best way is to add a message to every block that is encrypted using the block's private key and anyone else can decrypt the message using the block's public key. Is this possible? If yes, then how? I am using web3.js and solidity.

P.S- I know the concept of digital signature it is pretty much the same...but in my case I don't want to verify the user who has signed the block but I just want to verify if the block is from my website or not.

Comment: Nevertheless, use a signature. If you want to create a small signature, use a 256 bit elliptic curve (64 bytes). Any somewhat good encryption routine will take at least as many bytes of overhead. And, to be honest, any answer that does goes into creating such a "ciphertext" will go over your head and might not be secure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about development, this is about [crypto.se]. But we've got a selection of questions that address that signature generation is different from encryption with the private key over there.

Comment: Note that there is such a thing a signatures giving message recovering for e.g. RSA. However, you got to keep in mind that that will likely expand the message more than ECDSA, and the standard is outdated and barely used (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/17846/1172) for more info).

Comment: Hey @MaartenBodewes , I understand what you are saying....Can you please give an example on how to implement message recovering in solidity and web3js?

Comment: Uh, basically that's a "no".